# Xcode project using Cmake

Tags: xcode, cmake

Let us assume I have a folder called proj. proj has subfolders, and is a cpp project, with .h and .cpp files. Can someone suggest how to build this proj into an Xcode project using Cmake, so that I don't have to go through the cumbersome process inside the IDE. I've tried that and have failed miserably due to linker errors.
Can someone suggest me a way?

Also, this post will be further helpful for CMake beginners, myself being one.

Comment: What language are you programming in? With tiny bit more detail I can write a basic CMakeLists.txt file for you.